# Which variable declaration should be used?

Tags: java, variables

I want to write perfect Java code, so please let me ask this question.

I want to use a never-changing `String` variable in my method like this:

```
1. String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
```

And I could define it just in my method, and because it doesn't need to change, I could also define it in my class like this:

```
2. private final String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
3. private static final String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
4. public final String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
5. public static final String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
```

Here is my **question**: from way1-way5, which one is the best, and could you please explain why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `"I want to make perfect java code"`: then quit right now because this will never happen, even if your name were James Gosling. :) Myself, I'm trying to create "good enough" code.

Comment: If I just want to use that variable only in that class, so I think I should define it in class and just "final"....

Comment: Declare it final if it is not going to be changed and *private* if it only needs to be visible inside of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. If you want others (outside of your class) to be able to view it, then use `public` not `private`, and vice versa. Other than that, I would certainly use `static final` because you essentially want to define an unchanging constant, as you said. `static` because each instantiation of your class will not require a different value, and `final` because its value will not change.

Comment: Hi A.R.S, thank you. If I just want to define an unchanging constant only used in my class, could I use "private final"?

Comment: Yes definitely, `private static final String VAR = "Abc"`.

Comment: Oh, yes you could do that also. You should do that if you want a unique value of the variable for each instance of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Since it will never change, you don't need more than one copy of it across all of your class instances, so make it static.

Again, since it will never change, make it final, so that the compiler will report an error if code does try to change it. (There may be runtime performance advantages as well).

Whether it should be public or private depends on whether you have need to expose it to other classes. Prefer private, and make it public only if necessary.

So, either private static final or public static final (if necessary).

Comment: Thank you. Could "private final" be ok?

Comment: Having it non-static won't change how your program works, but it will "waste" both memory and time, as the member will now be instantiated once for each class instance, whereas making it static gives you one instance of the member regardless of how many instances of the class you allocate.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to use a never change String variable
```

As per your requirement i suggest you to create a class called ConstantCodes.java. This class is going to store all these kinds of variable in it. You can declare variable in it as follows. You can declare variable as `final` as it's value is not going to change.

```
public class ConstantCodes 
{
     public static final String STR4SEARCH_START = "Abc";
     ...
     ...
}
```

You can directly access this variable from any class like below,

```
String myNewVariable = ConstantCodes.STR4SEARCH_START;
```